# TableView data is not visible on simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I am using a TableView to show an array of data, but when I compile the application it seems that the TableView's function is not being called. Below is the code that I am using for this purpose :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)TableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return listdata.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"myCell"];    
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell =  [[ UITableViewCell alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    }

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.listdata objectAtIndex:row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: have you set datasource and delegate to your tableview?

Comment: print console in numberOfRowsInSection delegate, NSLog(@"count %d",listdata.count);

Comment: what is listdata.count ???? is it a NSArray ???

Comment: yes see [self.listdata objectAtIndex:row];

Answer (score 1):

If you're nto using a `UITableViewController` but simply adding a `UITableView` in a `UIViewController`, you need to set the delegate and datasource of your TableView to the VC's class.

You can do this in your storyboard, by ctrl-dragging from the TableView to the ViewController and choosing delegate/datasource, or you can do it programmatically by putting this code in the ViewController's .m, in the `viewDidLoad` method :

```
_tableView.delegate = self;
_tableView.datasource = self;
```

and add `<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDatasource>` to your ViewController's .h :

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDatasource>
```